# Function still raises exception even with catch statement

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Im suffering from a weird issue

basically I have the function

```
msg.guild.members.unban(userID)
```

This function returns a promise

I then use a .then statement for further code after the promise has been fulfilled

```
msg.guild.members.unban(element)
         .then(function() {console.log("worked")})
```

Anyways this function will in certain cases raise an Exception

Therefore I use the .catch statement to handle it

```
msg.guild.members.unban(element)
         .catch(console.log("Not banned"))
         .then(function() {})
```

However this does not seem to work

as a discord api error will still be raised and the program terminated

The error is an DiscordAPIError

Even if I remove the .then statement and just have a catch statement the program is still terminated

```
msg.guild.members.unban(element)
   .catch()
```

Comment: Can you share the complete error message with us?

Comment: I tried switching it around a bit however the exception still arose

Comment: And `catch(console.log("Not banned"))` should be `catch(() => console.log("Not banned"))` as `catch` accepts a function to be called when the promise is rejected.